# How get data from two models with the same foreign key in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to make a user panel in which userprofile info (like avatar, joined date, etc.) are to be displayed along with their topics. Here is the view:

```
def topic(request, topic_id):
    """Listing of posts in a thread."""
    posts = Post.objects.select_related('creator') \
        .filter(topic=topic_id).order_by("created")
    posts = mk_paginator(request, posts, DJANGO_SIMPLE_FORUM_REPLIES_PER_PAGE)
    topic = Topic.objects.get(pk=topic_id)
    topic.visits += 1
    topic.save()

    return render_to_response("myforum/topic.html", add_csrf(request, posts=posts, pk=topic_id,
        topic=topic), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The Topic model is:

```
class Topic(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=10000, null=True)
    forum = models.ForeignKey(Forum)
    created = models.DateTimeField()
    creator = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True)
    visits = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

And the UserProfile model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(
        max_length=20, choices= COUTNRY_CHOICES, blank=True)
    avatar = ImageWithThumbsField(), upload_to='images', sizes=((32,32),(150,150),(200,200)), blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, blank=True)
```

The problem is how best to join these two tables so that userprofile fields can be displayed in topic.html along with username?

Comment: What is your Django version?

Comment: @AamirAdnan it is 1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are already joined. You can get from a topic to the profile via `my_topic.user.userprofile.name` etc.

Comment: This does not display anything: `{{topic.user.userprofile.name}}` . Nor does this:  `{{topic.creator.userprofile.name}}` while the userprofile has a name. Any clues?

Comment: Please not that UserProfile is connected to User model through OneToOneField not a ForeignKey (though not sure this makes any difference).

Comment: It should be `creator`. Are you sure the relevant user has a UserProfile?

Comment: Yes user has a profile. I can see the values in database.

Answer (score 1):

As `Topic` model has `ForeignKey` to user model, in `topic.html` you can simply first access user and then its profile:

```
{% with topic.creator as user %}
    {% if user %}
        <p>Username: {{ user.username }}</p>
        <p>Email: {{ user.email }}</p>
        {% with user.userprofile as profile %}
            <p>Name: {{ profile.name }}</p>
            <p>City: {{ profile.city }}</p>
            <!-- More data here -->
        {% endwith %}
    {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```

You can read more about accessing related objects [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#one-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Well apart from `email` which is fetched from User model none of the profile-specific fields are displayed.